# Failing to update the cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

For one of the test AKS clusters I am trying to update, it gives the following error.

Error: SkuNotAvailable.
Message: The requested VM size for resource "Following SKUs have failed for capacity restrictions:
Standard_D4s_v4' is currently not available in location 'SouthAfricaNorth'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or different size.

I have checked and found that the quota is available in the subscription for this SKU and region selected.
Now cluster and pools went in to failed status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this error "SkuNotAvailable" is either a capacity issue in the region or that your SUBSCRIPTION doesn't have access to that specific size

You could once verify that by running the below Azure cli command
az vm list-skus --location centralus --size Standard_D --all --output table

If a SKU isn't available for your subscription in a location or zone that meets your business needs, submit a [SKU request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/region-access-request-process) to Azure Support.

If the subscription doesn't have access, please reach out to azure subscription and quota mgmt support team through as support case to check and make sure it's available to use the particular size on your subscription in case they cannot enable that for any reason, there will be an appropriate explanation.
At this point there is nothing can be done at the AKS side.

Comment: I'm getting the same error:
az vm list-skus --location centralindia --size Standard_D2s_v5 --all --output table
ResourceType     Locations     Name             Zones    Restrictions
---------------  ------------  ---------------  -------  --------------
virtualMachines  CentralIndia  Standard_D2s_v5  1,2,3    None

Comment: The requested VM size for resource 'Following SKUs have failed for Capacity Restrictions: Standard_D2s_v5' is currently not available in location 'CentralIndia'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or different zone.